# iCloud Family Sharing: Notifications to others member if you leave?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

If I leave Family Sharing will it notify anybody of this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any notifications of leaving. The family admin may be alerted or they'll see that you have left if they check, but that hasnt been shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Everyone in the family will get a notification in their notifications center.